# SQLite query to get data from multiple tables

Tags: sqlite

I have 4 tables,

> **ModTable**
>   file_id, mod_flag
>
> **TrackTable**
>   artist_id
>   album_id
>   file_id
>   title
>
> **AlbumTable**
>   album_id, album
>
> **ArtistTable**
>   artist_id, artist

I need to get artist_id, album_id, album, artist, fid, title from these tables for all file_id where mod_flag=1

So far what I did is (pseudo code)

```
 1. SELECT file_id, artist_id, album_id, title FROM TrackTable WHERE file_id IN (SELECT file_id FROM ModTable WHERE mod_flag=1);
```

In extreme cases, this will return about 30000 file_ids. So for all these file_ids,

```
 2. for(int count=0; count < noOfRecords/*30000*/; count++)          
    SELECT artist FROM ArtistTable WHERE artist_id==%llu     
    SELECT album FROM AlbumTable WHERE album_id==%llu
```

The above query works for me but I wanted to know whether this an optimized way to implement this. Should I avoid queries inside a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normaly you would join the tables like below. This should result in a better performance, because joins can be optimized by the query engine.

```
SELECT 
  t.file_id, 
  t.artist_id, 
  t.album_id, 
  t.title,
  a.album,
  ar.artist
FROM 
  TrackTable t 
  join AlbumTable a on t.album_id = a.album_id
  join ArtistTable ar on t.artist_id = ar.artist_id
WHERE t.file_id IN (SELECT file_id FROM ModTable WHERE mod_flag=1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the query. I did a performance comparison of this query & the one I mentioned (in the question). Your suggestion to use JOIN is about 10 seconds faster than using a query inside loop (tested in actual TI J6 hardware).